# orb opencv variable inputs

Tags: python, opencv, threshold, orb

I am new to opencv and am trying to extract keypoints of a gesture image by ORB algorithm in python interface. The image input is binary and has many curvatures. So ORB gives too many points as keypoints (which are actually not). I am trying to increase the threshold of ORB algorithm so that the unnesessary points dont get detected. I have searched for ORB algorithms and haven't found any use of threshold except for in c++ function description.
     So my question is what are the input parameters for ORB detection algorithm  and what is the actual syntax in python.
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The python docstring of `ORB_create` actually contains information about the parameter `nfeatures`, which is the maximum number of features to return. Could that solve your problem?

Comment: 'nfeatures' is the maximum number of fetures to retain.  My problem requires to increase the 'threshold' parameter.

Comment: According to the ORB paper, the threshold is set dynamically to detect more than `nfeatures` points. Then they are sorted according to the Harris measure and only the top `nfeatures` are returned. If you want your algorithm to be less sensitive, that seems to be the only way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the `ORB()` function in Opencv C++ description, I realized that the input parameters can be passed into function in Python as `nfeatures=200,mask=img` etc. (not sure about C++ though).